# Search by using bufdo command

Tags: vim

I do search phrase `not initiated` in all buffers in vim by using command:

```
:bufdo /not initiated
```

Have output below:

```
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
"aaa.cpp" [dos format] 1399 lines, 39255 characters
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
"bbb.cpp" [converted][dos format] 5829 lines, 235847 characters
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
"ccc.cpp" [dos format] 741 lines, 28473 characters
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
```

How to understand this output? Why so many lines `E486: Pattern not found: not initiated`. Does my search find something?

Comment: You might want to check out the [vi.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

All those `E486: Pattern not found: not initiated` in a row are from unnamed buffers. I don't know why you have so many, but you do. Each time Vim switched to a buffer with a filename, the filename and details are printed, hence `"aaa.cpp" [dos format] 1399 lines, 39255 characters`, etc.

For each buffer where the search failed, Vim prints an error message. But nothing's printed for buffers that did have something, so unless you had output like:

```
"aaa.cpp" [dos format] 1399 lines, 39255 characters
"bbb.cpp" [converted][dos format] 5829 lines, 235847 characters
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
"ccc.cpp" [dos format] 741 lines, 28473 characters
E486: Pattern not found: not initiated
```

Two filenames in a row without an error, there's no telling if anything was matched anywhere.

Comment: I have some buffers that are not displayed in vim tab's. Does this means that search is not possible if buffer is not displayed?

Comment: @vico this particular method is useless for searching, since it's never going to display anything useful. You should try something like `bufdo g/not initialized/p` or something from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30643432/2072269 instead